# Can't add extra information to model in view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to add a bit of extra information to an object in my view:

```
    photos = gallery.photos
    for p in photos:
        try:
            extra_info = SomethingElse.objects.filter(photo=p)[0]
            p.overlay = extra_info.image
            logger.debug(p.overlay.url)
        except:
            logger.debug('overlay not found')
            p.overlay = None

    return render_to_response('account/site.html',
                          {'photos': photos},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The logger outputs the urls I expect to see. In my template I just have:

```
<img src='{{ photo.overlay.url }}' alt='' />
```

inside a `for` loop. The photos themselves show up fine, but not the overlays.

What am I doing wrong? How should I be adding this extra information to the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess *photos* is a queryset. When you iterate over it django will return python objects reprsenting your data and when you do `p.overlay = extra_info.image` you are just modifying this python object, not the queryset. At the end of your loop, and because queryset results are cached by django, your local modifications are gone.

What I'd suggest is to pass to your template a list of dictionaries instead of a queryset. Something like:

```
photos = gallery.photos
photo_list = []
for p in photos:
    new_photo = {}
    new_photo['url'] = p.url
    # [...] copy any other field you need
    try:
        extra_info = SomethingElse.objects.filter(photo=p)[0]
        new_photo['overlay'] = extra_info.image
    except:
        logger.debug('overlay not found')
        new_photo['overlay'] = None
   photo_list.append(new_photo)

return render_to_response('account/site.html',
                      {'photos': photo_list},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

should work without any modification to your template :)

**UPDATE:**
I'm thinking of an other solution, maybe more elegant and for sure more effective: add an *overlay()* function to you class Model :

```
class Photo(models.Model):
  [...]

  def overlay(self)
    try:
      extra_info = SomethingElse.objects.filter(photo=self)[0]
      return extra_info.image
    except:
      logger.debug('overlay not found')
      return None
```

here you don't need to do anything special in your view, nor in your template!

Comment: Second answer works great, that's what I really should have done. Thanks!